# In a multiple column layout my highchart is not visible in Safari

Tags: safari, highcharts

I've written a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/929Zb/5/) for this that reduces the problem to the minimal markup that demonstrates the problem... which is my Highchart isn't being rendered in Safari (version 5.1.7 on Windows but I've also run it in the latest version on a MacBook.)

My requirement is a multiple column layout of widget as shown in this screenshot from the fiddle running in chrome :

[image: Chrome correctly displaying the chart]

and here's the same thing running in Safari :

[image: Safari does not show the chart]

Safari has rendered SVG and hovering over it in debug highlights the elements in blue in the HTML but it just can't be seen!!

The css I'm using to display the column is shown below. If you change the column count from 2 to 1 the chart displays fine in Safari!!

```
.widget-container
{
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 2em;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 2em;
}
.widget {
    /* This is required to keep the widget div's together and not break them over columns  */
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
margin-bottom: 2em; 
}
```

Is there a change to the CSS that will make Safari work or will this require a javascript fix? I pondered whether this was something to do with CSS transitions so tried turning off animations but given it's still animating I've clearly got the syntax wrong. I have a time constraint on this problem so I'm posting now but will report back if I have any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is some CSS problem with displaying chart in any column different than first one. If you disable colum-break-inside it also works.

What can I suggest is to disable position for chart container: http://jsfiddle.net/929Zb/17/

```
.highcharts-container {
    position: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. This worked flawlessly in the fiddle but when I applied it to my site it still doesn't work correctly. I'm going to try and isolate the conditions again and post another fiddle.

Comment: I've accepted your answer now since this does the trick in the fiddle. Given I also had other problems with other browsers using columns I've decided to use a Bootstrap fluid layout with two columns - it means my layouts don't always look great but it's solved the problem.

Oh... and to my embarrassment my graph also wasn't rendering in Safari because it wouldn't interpret Date.parse("2013-10-03") causing my graph data to be widely out (facepalm!)